# How Can I Pass A Variable e.g. /variable/ In a Mongo Query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to pass in searchTerm from a variable, how would I achieve this please?

```
const mongoquery = { description: { $in: [ /searchTerm/ ] } };
```

I initially tried with:

```
const mongoquery = { description: { $in: [ `/${searchTerm}/` ] } };
```

But, this doesn't work because the ` are included in the string:

```
{ description: { '$in': [ '/FAB/' ] } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) method,

```
const mongoquery = { description: { $in: [ new RegExp(searchTerm) ] } };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegExp in searchTerm like as

```
const mongoquery = { description: new RegExp(searchTerm, "i") };
```

For like search you can use like as

```
const mongoquery = { description: new RegExp("^" + searchTerm + "$", "i") };

  OR 

const mongoquery = { description: new RegExp(searchTerm + "$", "i") };
```